# Unable to run c Program through cmd2

Tags: c

I have a C file names Test1.c on my desktop, and the code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main ()
{
  printf ("I'm a C program\n");
}
```

Although when I follow what this guide tells me to do in cmd I still can't

run it:

```
host% gcc test1.c -o test1
host% ./test1
I'm a C program
host%
```

Comment: Your info seems to be jumbled.  How did you issue the commands?

Comment: You are probably doing this on Windows.  It might have been meant for Linux/Unix.

Comment: Where is your `this guide`?

Comment: That is no standard C code.

Comment: Did you `cd` to desktop?

Comment: @Olaf it is correct code in C89

Comment: @Jengo the output you posted is correct for that program. What problem are you having?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: That's why I wrote "no **standard** C code". Current - and only valid - standard is C11; all older versions have been withdrawn (whereas it is valid in C99, too). (Nit-picky? Maybe) People really should get used to it. Actually it was already legacy in C89/90; that version just did not require the compiler to warn about it. Such legacy stuff is one reason for the bad reputation of C (for good reasons).

Comment: @MattMcNabb: gcc 5.1 defaults to C11, btw. As OP does not specify why he "can't run it", gcc might report a warning for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why it's not working-

1. The pathname of the directory where this c code is, is not defined in environment variable path.
2. To compile the code, user must have installed the 'gcc' compiler on machine. If it's not installed, you can't compile the c code above.

Thanks.

Comment: 1) I don't think gcc uses `PATH` to find source code. 2) That should generate an error like "xxx not found" from the shell. This information is missing, you should request more information from OP in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you set path of gcc in  `Environment Variable` and then change directory to where your c program is using `cd` command .

After this when you are done-

To compile -

```
gcc Test1.c
```

after successful compilation `a.exe` will be created .

Run that `a.exe` in cmd using -

```
a.exe
```

And you program will be executed.

Comment: OP gives no information what is actually going wrong. It could be his keyboard is missing the `c` key, so he cannot type `gcc`. A proper answer would require more information.

Comment: @Olaf  That was epic , but that's can't the case so I just pointed to possible problem regarding path or maybe he just don't have gcc installed .